# How do I remove the commas from a select statement

Tags: python, sqlite

I have the following code

```
for item in lesson:
            result = connection.execute("SELECT bookingID FROM Booking WHERE lessonBooked = ? AND dateBooked = ? AND username = ?",([item,now1,self.username]))
            result = result.fetchall()
            if(len(result) > 0):
                for item2 in result:
                    print (item2)
                    result2 = connection.execute("SELECT roomNO FROM BookedRoom WHERE bookingID = ?",([item2]))
                    result2 = result2.fetchall()
                    print (result2)
```

The print item2 line outputs: 
(39,)
(43,)
(48,)
(49,)
The code then crashes when I add in the last 3 lines.
The output of item2 is expected but is there a way to remove the comma, as I suspect that the commas are causing the issue as the item2 list is then used to Select from BookedRoom table.

Comment: The commas aren't really "there". They just indicate that the values are 1-tuples. That could be the cause of the problem, if you're trying to use a tuple as an integer. Please provide the full traceback of the exception you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetchall` returns a sequence of sequences (commonly a list of tuples), no matter whether it returns one or many rows, nor if you select one or many attributes. So you can either use `item2[0]` or more simply just directly use the sequence:

```
result2 = connection.execute("SELECT roomNO FROM BookedRoom WHERE bookingID = ?", item2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for your 2nd execute line:

```
result2 = connection.execute("SELECT roomNO FROM BookedRoom WHERE bookingID = ?",([item2[0]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the print function is printing string then try this code:

```
for item in lesson:
            result = connection.execute("SELECT bookingID FROM Booking WHERE lessonBooked = ? AND dateBooked = ? AND username = ?",([item,now1,self.username]))
            result = result.fetchall()
            if(len(result) > 0):
                for item2 in result:
                    print (item2[:-1])
                    result2 = connection.execute("SELECT roomNO FROM BookedRoom WHERE bookingID = ?",(item2[:-1]))
                    result2 = result2.fetchall()
                    print (result2)
```

This will not consider last character from string.

Or you can try this:

```
result2 = connection.execute("SELECT roomNO FROM BookedRoom WHERE bookingID = ?",([item2[0]]))
```